# Static headers on a listview

Tags: android, listview, static, header

I have a ListActivity with obviously a ListView on it. This ListView consists of different sections, each of them have a header.

When I display the list of items to the user, first header is on top. If user scrolls, header is hidden and rest of items are displayed. I know how to make that simple header static, always on top, but what i want now, is to have last displayed header always on top.

Last version of GMail is a good example of what i want. While on a message, if you scroll, you will always see that message header on top. If you keep scrolling and go to next message, when that new message header is about to disappear because of the scrolling action, it will replace the current static header, so that user will have always current message's header on top, as a floating panel.

Is there any example out there, or some guidance about how to implement this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm looking for and example of this too. Did you find one?

Comment: No i didn't. I had to implement things differently

Answer (score 1):

I havn't tried this out but I think this could be done using a LinearLayout, in this example a TextView should remain static at the top:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
    android:text="row one"
    android:textSize="15pt"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Laurence for your answer!. I'd love it was that simple but i'm afraid this is not what i was looking for. I'm looking for something like a real floating panel. Take a look at Gmail app for a real example. Thanks though!